# How to create something like jQuery Accordion?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

We need to create a FAQ page that has a requirement that clicking the title will open up the answer.

[jQuery Accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) popped immediately to mind, and I have spent the last couple of days trying to get that to work with our code.

In short, it can't (at least, not easily) because migrating our version of jquery up from 1.7.1 causes a number of our other controls to break.

All of our controls load from a Template, like the one below:

```
<?php include(SITE_ROOT.'lib/templates/masterPage.php'); ?>
```

I could modify `masterPage.php` to use the latest jquery, but then we would need to stop all of our software department to spend the next few months regression testing. The company is not ready for that.

I have gotten Accordion to work with 1.8.3 and up (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/9LuAE/1/), but we are locked into 1.7.1 for now.

Is there something else out there that I can use to create this effect besides the latest jQuery?

Is there anything in HTML5? I can use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an accordion with HTML 5 and CSS3 see http://www.expression-web-tutorial.com/accordion-menu-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks Domm. Going to look at that now.

Comment: Looks good, might not be great on browser compatibility. Doubt it will work with ie7 or ie8 if you need to support them that is. Guess they are being dropped really anyway

Answer (score 2):

This is a really nice accordion with just plain CSS3, though if you support IE lower than 9, it won't be useful, as it use pseudo classes.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/21/accordion-with-css3/

There's also this other one that I remember adapting to my needs on a project I made about a year ago.

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3

Again, CSS3, IE will cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could try another accordion plugin, there 2 that are bundled with the two best frontend frameworks available

I believe foundation 4 may be compatible with your version of jQuery

http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download-f4.html 
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html

or

Bootstrap should work too.

http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/05/17/bootstrap-2-3-2-released/
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

^^^ This is an older version of bootstrap, the newest version might be compatible too. might be worth checking if you go down this route as you would want to be on the latest stable release really.

I prefer foundation by miles though

### UPDATE

Foundation don't seem to mention that any specific version of jQuery is required and there seems to be people using zurb foundation 5 with jquery 1.1..... and you can just choose the accordion using the customise tab http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation

Comment: LOL - we are running an antique version of **Bootstrap**, too.

Comment: Guess its not bundled in with that one then... I believe zurb foundation is modular and you can just pick the bits you want

Comment: This is the latest version but might still work. they don't seem to mention that any specific version of jQuery is required and there seems to be people using zurb foundation 5 with jquery 1.1..... and you can just choose the accordion using the customise tab http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation